# How can I make an inline SVG always fill out the screen?

Tags: svg, scale, responsiveness, inline-svg

I've created a vector image, which I'd like to use as a hero for my website. It should fill out the width and height of the viewport at all resolutions.

Furthermore I need to be able to animate the SVG's elements via CSS or JavaScript, so inserting it as a css background or an img isn't an option (at least as far as I know).

Do you guys know a way to solve this?
This image shows, what I'd like to achieve: [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" is what you want I think.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Got it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it to work, thanks to Robert Longson's comment:
Applying `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` and 100% width & height to the SVG worked.

You can see it here: http://codepen.io/EigenDerArtige/pen/yMaXZx

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute `preserveAspectRatio="slice"` to the SVG. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio for details.

Comment: none doesn't seem to match what is required as the pictures show no change in aspect ratio. Instead they are cut in whichever direction overflows.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ah, I didn't look at the pictures closely enough. "slice" instead of "none" should do what's intended.

Comment: That's still invalid as you can't have slice on its own it must be preceded by a valid align value.

Comment: This worked for me for what I was going for

Answer (score 0):

The preferred svg image filling the screen are shown cropped. As you work with SVG I believe you may want the entire image centered nicely filling the screen without any cropping. The example code below will load an svg file and fill the screen, centering the SVG. All elements are accessible for css and javascript changes.
This will also respond to window resize.

Copy the below to an HTML file, adding your own svg file URL  and uncomment the onload event

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Load SVG file - full screen</title>
</head>
<body style='padding:0px;font-family:arial'>
<div id=svgDiv style='width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;'></div>
<script>
function loadSVG()
{
 var SVGFile="...your SVG file..."
 var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
 loadXML.onload = callback;
 loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
 loadXML.send();
 function callback()
 {
  //---responseText---
   svgDiv.innerHTML=loadXML.responseText
         sizeFull()
 }
}
//--onload, onresize----
function sizeFull()
{
 var mySVG=document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
   var svgW=window.innerWidth
 var svgH=window.innerHeight
    var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
 var bbx=bb.x
 var bby=bb.y
 var bbw=bb.width
 var bbh=bb.height

    mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",bbx+" "+bby+" "+bbw+" "+bbh )
    mySVG.setAttribute("width",svgW)
    mySVG.setAttribute("height",svgH)
}
window.onresize=sizeFull
//document.addEventListener("onload",loadSVG(),false)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```